# Ask Django - Nginx Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'attacker.web'. You may need to add 'attacker.web' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, nginx

recently i had this error message in my sentry

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'attacker.web'. You may need to add 'attacker.web' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

and i saw the request like this

```
curl \
 -H "Accept: */*" \
 -H "Content-Length: " \
 -H "Content-Type: " \
 -H "Forwarded: for=\"attacker.web:8888\";by=\"attacker.web:9999\"" \
 -H "Host: attacker.web" \
 -H "User-Agent: Report Runner" \
 -H "X-Forwarded-For: " \
 -H "X-Forwarded-Host: mysite.com" \
 -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" \
 -H "X-Real-Ip: " \
 "https://attacker.web/subpage/"
```

how do i prevent this kind of request ? and what's the name of the attack ?

i've been config my nginx to

1. drop curl request
2. return 444 when the host name doesn't the same with server_name

how to deal with this kind of request ?

Comment: These are usually scanners running on the web trying different vulnerability permutations in a hope that any one might hit and they can compromise your server. You can look at tools like [Fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically block such scanners and get rid of their generated logs.

Comment: It's kind of weird, because I've already create strict rule in nginx server, create a middleware to validate the host and site, but still the request pass to uwsgi server.. because from the request you can saw that they are forwarded the request to my host, that's why every validation seems to be didn't work..

Comment: I'll try the tools you mentioned, tq